# How to use differents XML ack messages responses in one web service channel

Tags: mirth

I have one web service listener channel with differents destinations.

All of this destinations are channel writers.
All of this channels haves a custom acks than sends back like response to the first channel (the web service channel), when is processed for the correct channel.

I need to prepare the web service channel response ready for sending any of this responses from any of the channels. How can I do it?

Now I can only select one of the destinations in "response" in the "source settings" of the web service channel, and send a custom ack response from only one channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To each of Web Service Listener channel’s destinations open the Response Transformer and add a JS step. In that step store a response (code) from underlying channels to a Channel Map. Then go to the WS Listener Postprocessor and create a generic response stored in the Response Map. This map is what you need to configure on the Source connector as an ACK.